# Getting errors when I try to run my flutter app

Tags: flutter

When I run my flutter project I get this error

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

So I run flutter clean or delete my build folder manually, and then
run flutter pub get before running my flutter project, it then runs successfully, though
when compiling I get this error messages:

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_analytics-9.1.12\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\analytics\FlutterFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_dynamic_links-4.3.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\dynamiclinks\FlutterFirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-11.4.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\JobIntentService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\local_auth-1.1.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\localauth\LocalAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(23939): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51876/WyzGLXWyh3M=/ws
Finished with error: FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = 'C:\Users\USER\Downloads\Project\Tutorials\Documets\Flutter Tech Project\project1\New Code\dart_files\skyline-user\build\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\io\flutter\plugins\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle\*' (OS Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
, errno = 3)
```

But it still works.

But anytime I want to rerun the flutter project I get the first error above, unless I run
flutter clean or delete the build folder manually & then run flutter pub get. So I have
to follow thesame process over & over again for me to compile and run my flutter project.

It is stressfull doing same process over and over again.

What could be the problem?